# AttributeError: lower not found; removing infrequent features from Sklearn CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

## Make corpus and vocab

```
K = 10
XYtr['description'] = XYtr['description'].fillna("nan")
Xte['description'] = Xte['description'].fillna("nan")
corpus = list(XYtr['description'])+list(Xte['description'])
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
corpus = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components = K)
lda.fit(corpus)
#There are no problems until here

# Create a list of (term, frequency) tuples sorted by their frequency
sum_words = corpus.sum(axis=0) 
words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()]
words_freq = sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1])

# Keep only the terms in a list
vocabulary, _ = zip(*words_freq[:int(total_features * 0.2)])
vocabulary = list(vocabulary)

#Finally, we use the vocabulary to limit the model to the less frequent terms.
bottom_vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)
topics = bottom_vect.fit_transform(corpus)
```

This returned "AttributeError: lower not found" on the last line of code. I therefore cannot get "topics".

It would be greatly appreciated for some suggestions.

Here are few rows of my dataset

XYtr:

[image]

Xte:

[image]

Comment: please provide a few rows of the data as well so this can be replicated

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because you wrote over `corpus` with the result of `CountVectorizer()` . Using an example:

```
corpus = ['This is the first document.',
'This document is the second document.',
'And this is the third one.',
'Is this the first document?']
```

Assign results of the `CountVectorizer()` to another object `X` :

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components = 2)
lda.fit(X)

sum_words = X.sum(axis=0) 
words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()]
words_freq = sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1])

total_features = len(words_freq)
vocabulary, _ = zip(*words_freq[:int(total_features * 0.2)])
vocabulary = list(vocabulary)
```

Then rerun your CountVectorizer :

```
bottom_vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)
topics = bottom_vect.fit_transform(corpus)
```